# Fedora 36 Desktop Linux only single bluetooth earbud is pairing

Tags: linux, bluetooth, fedora-36

I’ve recently installed Fedora 36 on a mini tablet/laptop (Linx 1010) and generally runs well, but the Bluetooth earbuds (LG Tone FPS5) aren’t connecting properly.

I’m able to pair one of the earbuds, but not the other one: they don’t pair together.

Any ideas how I can get this resolved?

Comment: Probably set to `handsfree head unit`, ie, single speaker & mike rather than `High Fidelity Feedback`. Change it in your audio setup.

Comment: I upgraded to Fedora 37 and now both earbuds pair as one and this works with high fidelity. The only issue is that the mix from the earbuds isn’t being recognised. So just using the laptop mic for  now.